# Is there a character entity that means nothing at all?

Tags: html, css, escaping, character

I'm trying to use markup to create a Text node in an html document which does not affect the presentation and has no semantic meaning in order to get the [`:empty`](https://devdocs.io/css/:empty) pseudo-class to trigger.

Here's the code ([copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084468/712334)):

```css
th::after { content: attr(data-value) }
td::after { content: attr(data-value) }
td[data-value]:not(:empty) {
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th data-value="Peter"></th>
    <td data-value="male">&#x0200B;</td>
    <td data-value="34"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th data-value="Susanne"></th>
    <td data-value="female"></td>
    <td data-value="12"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th data-value="Lucas"></th>
    <td data-value="male">&#x0200B;</td>
    <td data-value="41"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After reviewing the [Character Entity Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) it's unclear to me if the `ZeroWidthSpace` would be suitable for this purpose:

```
<td>&ZeroWidthSpace;</td>
```

Is there a way to use html markup to create Text nodes without any semantic meaning?

Comment: I guess not. Every HTML entity has a strong semantic meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALT+0160
&nbsp;
&#160;
\00A0
```

This might work? It's a non-breaking space

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This would be great except for fact they can affect the presentation slightly—why I went with the ZeroWidthSpace. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Marking answered as no better answers have been given. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Over a year later I learned [there is indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961339/712334) a null entity reference to create a text node without any meaning:

`&#0;` also written as `&#x0;`.

Depending on one's interpretation of "no meaning" in the context of other questions, additional potential answers include:

- `&#x2400;` or the ␀ character NUL
- `&#x2205;` or the ∅ character Empty Set